# Super simple jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created the most simple though still quite flexible jQuery slider ever! Or at least, I hope so.

```
var slider = $(".slider-ul");

slider.each(function () {

    var e = $(this),
        images = e.find("li"),
        current = null;

    slide();

    function slide() {

        images.each(function() {

            var li = $(this),
                next,
                pDone = false,
                sDone = false;

            if (li.hasClass("primary")) {
                li.removeClass("primary");
                pDone = true;
            } else if (li.hasClass("secondary")) {
                li.removeClass("secondary").addClass("primary");

                next = li.next();

                console.log(next);
                if (next.size()) {
                    next.addClass("secondary");
                    sDone = true;
                } else {
                    images.filter(":first").addClass("secondary");
                    sDone = true;
                }
            }

            if (sDone && pDone) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        setTimeout(slide, 5000);

    }
});
```

How does this look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code, you set `sDone = true` in both branches of the `if-else`:

> ```
> if (next.size()) {
>     next.addClass("secondary");
>     sDone = true;
> } else {
>     images.filter(":first").addClass("secondary");
>     sDone = true;
> }
> ```

So you could move that line outside of the `if-else`:

```
if (next.size()) {
    next.addClass("secondary");
} else {
    images.filter(":first").addClass("secondary");
}
sDone = true;
```

---

At the top you declared the `current` variable,
but then you don't use it. If you don't need it, then remove it.